# how to indicate on a 1 page resume that you have more working experience than listed?

Tags: resume, work-experience

should I indicate that I can disclose full working experience upon request?

Comment: What format is your resume (ie are you just listing job company, title  and period or more detail?)

Comment: Listing job title, company, period & description of duties, yes..

Comment: In what way do you have more experience? One page should be able to list/summarise your work history

Comment: Suggested dupe that most closely matches the question asked. The real answer is that **you should use a two page resume**. See the questions on that topic on this site that explain when to use a one or two page resume.

Answer (score 0):

Listing 'description of duties' might be overkill for a one page resume; I would indeed keep a separate resume with full details and note on the 1-page that details & references are available upon request.

Some companies use this 1-page resume as a way to screen out candidates that don't meet their idea of having proper experience.

Comment: Thanks so much! Im mainly listing duties in bullets under every job title. My 1 pager resembles a T in that i start with a summary of contact info & attributes relevant to my experience, and then unfold everything else (past experience, education, languages,etc) in 2 columns.

Apparently, if i go with 2 pages i've lost attention from what I've read ..

Comment: If the company doesn't strictly require a 1 page resume, then I wouldn't stress to much about spilling *a little* over onto two pages (make sure to list references and general skills on that second page instead of the 1st one, if you list those at all).

While the general recommendation is to stick to one page, it's a guideline and not a rule in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

How many years of experience do you have, and what kinds of jobs are you leaving out? If, for example, you're a few years out of school and starting to drop your undergrad part time or summer experience from your resume, that's totally normal and expected. Generally, titling your work section "Relevant Experience" is a good way of conveying that you may have had other jobs that aren't as relevant for the application. Definitely cut less relevant jobs to stay on one page. My rule of thumb (though other people definitely have different opinions): until you're VP-level+, do not go onto a second page. It's rare, early in your career, to have so much truly relevant work experience that you can't cut bullets or whole jobs to make your resume one page. Obviously, YMMV, different strokes for different folks, etc.